# How can I restore the traditional console in Spyder?

Tags: spyder

Recent versions of Spyder have removed the traditional console, and now only include the IPython console. (See https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder/issues/4524) Is there any way to add it back?

**UPDATE:** I have accepted the answer given by the Spyder maintainer, which is "No", as it is the answer to the question. The question itself is somewhat inchoate, and I note here that it is possible to just install a previous version of Spyder. The last version with the traditional console is 3.1.4. Anaconda Python makes this fairly easy to install a previous version:

1. Launch Anaconda Navigator.
2. Activate the virtual environment in which you wish to install a previous version of Spyder.
3. On the Home screen, you will see several tools such as IPython, Jupyter, and Spyder.
4. In the box for Spyder, click the gear icon, "Install specific version", and 3.1.4:

[image]

Comment: Can you make your update an answer? I think that's the good way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(*Spyder maintainer here*) No, unfortunately there's no way to add it back again.

We decided to remove it because of all the problems the Python console had, as mentioned in the issue you referenced above in your question.